# Hibernate Unable to Start On Large-Scale Database

Tags: hibernate, performance, startup

I have been using Hibernate + HSQLDB on my desktop for developing a database adapter for my application. For legacy reasons, the IDs are generated by the application as strings. All was working fine then.

Now, we have a pre-prod database, with a bit more than a million records. I had to do some changes (e.g. identifier too long) on the Hibernate side, but nothing major.

That is, until I got to this problem. When I try to start my application on the pre-prod server, Hibernate starts making a gazillion queries, which eventually end up in a OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. Increasing the heap max is not helping.

I have disabled C3PO cache settings and disabled hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto. I don't know why it is making these queries, and I don't know how to disable them.

Can anyone help me??????

Comment: What sort of queries is it executing? Hibernate doesn't make queries on its own, it issues them because your application has asked it to.

Comment: You are right. I had a dummy query on startup to make sure that we touched the database. I removed that and I'm able to start the application. But this is only shifting the problem, as the moment any DB request is executed, the gazillion queries are executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You told Hibernate to fetch eagerly. So when you load the first object, Hibernate starts to fetch all related objects, too.

You must set all unnecessary relations to `fetch=LAZY`.

Comment: That's good. I disabled all the fetch options (thus letting Hibernate figure it out with its defaults) and I don't have this situation.
However, I have blocking behaviour now.

:(

Comment: You must find a balance between lazy and eager fetching. And you must make sure you use the correct transaction nesting. Good luck debugging this. I'd usually suggest test cases but it's hard to come up with tests for deadlocks.